# SetAccessControl throwing UnauthorizedAccessException for Windows Service

Tags: c#, windows

I'm writing a Windows service, and one of the things I need it to do is set permissions on the installation directory of my program to prohibit write access to any user except administrators (to prevent tampering).

Right now, I'm failing to get the most basic change to work, giving "Everyone" Read & Execute permissions on the directory. The error I get is:

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

And my code:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);

SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
SecurityIdentifier system = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null);

DirectorySecurity dSecurity = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow));
Directory.SetAccessControl(path, dSecurity);
```

My service is running as "LocalSystem", NOT "LocalService", so I don't know why I don't have access to do this.

Comment: Where is the folder in question?  Have you checked the permissions to see whether `SYSTEM` has full access?